# Is this orange line on film scans operator error or a camera defect?

Tags: film, olympus

[image]

I just bought a used Olympus Stylus Infinity with Zoom 35mm camera. I *love* how the photos came back, but they all have an orange line across them. Is this something that can be fixed? Anyone know what it could be?

Comment: Is it on the film also, or just the scans? If it is on the film, is it all films?

Comment: haven't gotten the films back yet. sent to a lab to develop. i did get other film from another film camera developed at the same lab, no orange line... may have to wait till i get the film back to see for sure.

Answer (score 1):

That line (low resolution) looks like a scanning defect, where the linear array isn't properly zero'd out. It should be in the exact same pixel place (assuming the images aren't cropped) on every single image.

If the tone of the line changes, or waves around, then it could be a light leak. However you'll need to look at the negatives to determine that.

If it is a scanning defect, a rescan should remove it.